# Is my disk failing?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, storage, sata

I'm troubleshooting a Debian Buster system that occasionally becomes unresponsive. Looking at `dmesg`, I see some alarming messages pop up:

```
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:47 2023] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4050000 action 0xe frozen                                   
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:47 2023] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed                                                   
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:47 2023] ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake DevExch }                                                              
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:47 2023] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:47 2023] ata1.00: cmd 35/00:18:68:02:96/00:00:1d:00:00/e0 tag 19 dma 12288 out                                     
                                    res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)                               
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:47 2023] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:47 2023] ata1: hard resetting link
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:48 2023] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)                                                    
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:48 2023] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible                                           
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:48 2023] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible                                           
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:48 2023] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:48 2023] ata1: EH complete
[Wed Apr 19 19:39:48 2023] ata1.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

These messages (which repeat) would seem to suggest that the SATA link needs to be reset every few minutes.

I ran an extended the SMART test of `/dev/sda` and it doesn't detect any failures ([full log](https://gist.github.com/rgov/97bd303ce6fa8936ed95011f44cfb25e)):

```
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-5.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 860 PRO 512GB
Serial Number:    S5HTNE0N107136V
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 e2014235a
Firmware Version: RVM02B6Q
User Capacity:    512,110,190,592 bytes [512 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Apr 20 08:10:54 2023 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]
Wt Cache Reorder: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
[...]

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   096   096   000    -    16420
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   099   099   000    -    372
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     PO--C-   099   099   000    -    17
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   PO--C-   100   100   010    -    0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  -O--CK   100   100   010    -    0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  -O--CK   100   100   010    -    0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       PO--C-   100   100   010    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O--CK   079   045   000    -    21
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O-RC-   200   200   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   100   100   000    -    0
235 Unknown_Attribute       -O--C-   099   099   000    -    230
241 Total_LBAs_Written      -O--CK   099   099   000    -    9965553603

[...]

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     16411         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16406         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16405         -
```

I don't think it's the filesystem's fault but nonetheless I tried the kernel command line option `fsck.mode=force`, but it doesn't appear that it actually checked my disk other than the EFI partition.

Is this indicative of a certain failure mode, like a faulty disk, a bad connection, or a corrupt filesystem?

Comment: Running `fsck` with a disk in this state could completely wreck your filesystem. Don't do that

Comment: @roaima added SMART extended test output

Comment: It could be the drive (this is most likely, but it's worth checking other possibly cheaper-to-fix options first)...it could be the sata port, or the sata cable, or the sata power cable. Or the power supply. or your motherboard or sata controller card.   It could even be electrical noise from a nearby motor (e.g. a fridge or pump)...which would indicate cheap, poor-quality sata cables (either move the machine or look for shielded sata cables).  Also, try re-seating all the cables (i.e. unplug them, clear any dust, and plug them back in) and make sure they're firmly connected.

Comment: Is there any pattern to when it happens? e.g. in the afternoon when the heating/cooling turns on or when the HAM enthusiast up the street gets home from work?  or when the drive (or something else in the system - be especially wary of other devices in the same IOMMU group) is under heavy load?

Comment: Disk SMART looks fine. I'd say it was the cable or something related to it